# Design issue in Spring app: in which layer (web, service or repository) should I retrieve the currently logged in user?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I work on a CRUD Spring app. Let me explain a basic use case:

A user can save an **`Advertisement`**. As of now I **retrieve the currently logged in member in the web/controller layer** and then **pass it on to the service layer** so that it **can be set on the advertisement** (the currently logged in user is the owner of the Advertisement; it is retrieve using Spring Security and my custom annotation: `@CurrentMember`).

In **controller layer:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/family/new", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String newFamilyAdvertisement(
        @ModelAttribute("advertisementInfo") @Validated(value = ValidationGroups.AdvertisementCreation.class) FamilyAdvertisementInfo familyAdvertisementInfo,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, @CurrentMember Member member) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateFamilyAdvertisementModel(model, familyAdvertisementInfo, member);
        return "advertisement/family/new";
    }
    advertisementService.createAdvertisement(member, familyAdvertisementInfo.getAdvertisement(), familyAdvertisementInfo.getAddressReference());
    return "redirect:/advertisement/family/new";
}
```

In **service layer:**

```
@Override
public void createAdvertisement(Member member, Advertisement advertisement, String addressReference) {
    if (member == null || advertisement == null || addressReference == null || addressReference.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("One argument is null or empty");
    }
    Address address = geolocationService.retrieveAddressFromReference(addressReference);
    advertisement.setAddress(address);
    advertisement.setMember(member);//SET CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USER
    advertisement.setValidated(Boolean.FALSE);
    advertisement.setActive(Boolean.TRUE);
    advertisement.setCreationDate(utils.now());
    saveAdvertisement(advertisement);
}
```

Still in **service layer**(Roo ITD):

```
public void AdvertisementServiceImpl.saveAdvertisement(Advertisement advertisement) {
    advertisementRepository.save(advertisement);
}
```

Now the interrogation I have is:

- Should I retrieve the current user/member **as early as possible** (here in the web layer) and then pass it on until it is needed (here in the service layer)? ***OR***
- Should I retrieve the current user/member **only when I need it** (here in the service layer)?

Answer (score -1):

Thats a matter of design and choices you need to made, usually you dont need to bother controller to pass member to service. It doesnt need any knowledge about user. You can easily load it in service so you api is shorter/cleaner.

But, in a case your api is used from some external project - then api should show what objects are needed to make it work.

To sum up, in your case I would load it in service.